# how to set 'this' object(TableLayout) by findViewById?

Tags: android, this, findviewbyid

I defined my own tableLayout that extents TableLayout.
In my class I'm trying to create MyTableLayout object:

```
int tableLayoutId = R.id.tableLayoutId;
MyTableLayout tableLayout = new MyTableLayout(this);
tableLayout.createTableLayout(tableLayoutId);
```

**In the last line above, the object tableLayout calls the function 'createTableLayout'. In this function, I'm trying to set it('this' object) by findviewById but I'm doing something silly I guess. So How should I set it?**

```
public class MyTableLayout extends TableLayout {

    public MyTableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void createTableLayout(int tableLayoutId) {

        // what should I write here(instead the line below) in order to let 
        // 'this' have the returned view from findViewById

        this = (MyTableLayout) findViewById(tableLayoutId);
        ...
    }
}
```

**OR MAYBE I SHOULD DO IT OTHER WAY?**

**====================================**

**=============== EDIT ================**

**====================================**

After reading cricket comment, I changed the code in my class:

```
if (getResources() != null) {
    MyTableLayout tableLayout = (MyTableLayout)
        getResources().getLayout(R.layout.tableLayout);
    if (tableLayout != null) {
        tableLayout.createTableLayout();
    }
}
```

my xml contains MyTableLayout object that I would like to create a table programmatically through it.

and my MyTableLayout looks so:

```
public class MyTableLayout extends TableLayout {

public MyTableLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void createTableLayout() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
            MyButton myButton = new MyButton(getContext(), buttonId, buttonViewHeight, buttonViewWidth, buttonViewText);
            myButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(buttonViewHeight, buttonViewWidth));
            tableRow.addView(myButton);
        }
        addView(tableRow, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}
```

}

and now my app crashes. Do you know why?

the breakpoint reaches this line and crashes:

```
MyTableLayout tableLayout = (MyTableLayout)
        getResources().getLayout(R.layout.tableLayout);
```

Comment: You can't assign `this`... `new MyTableLayout(this);` from the Activity already created your class. It doesn't need an ID. Alternatively, you should be able to add your TableLayout class to the Activity xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

succeeded finally.

**1.**

I removed the MyTableLayout from the xml.

**2.**

In the class' onCreate I accessed the layout where I want to add MyTableLayout:

```
linearLayoutGame = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

**3.**

I created and added it to the this layout

```
MyTableLayout tableLayout = new MyTableLayout(this);
tableLayout.createTableLayout();
linearLayout.addView(tableLayout);
```

Comment: You can call `createTableLayout` in the constructor of `MyTableLayout`, if you want